# Need help removing recessed canister light without a screw

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

I need to remote a Halo H572RICAT recessed light canister. It has a CFL and I want to remove the ballast so need to remove the can.

There are no screws for sure. I can't see any small slot either that I move the canister to. There seems to be 4 clips that don't move whatsoever. They had like a mini foamy sticker on them. Any help appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The "mini foamy sticker" is better understood as a gasket, since these appear to be IC  (insulation contact) housings which are not ventilated by design. Have you tried rotating the housing counterclockwise?

Answer (score 3):

I found this picture of H572RICAT in a Halo catalog

[image]

and then I scribbled on it...

To remove the fitting you need to withdraw the curved springs at the base, a flat bladed tool may be used to lever the top part of the vertical part of the spring into the can

Doing this should allow the fitting to be removed and the mains cable accessed.

Comment: Thanks @Jasen. I tried to use a flat screwdriver and lever the clips out where the red arrows are. I tried a lot of force but just couldn't unclip them. The tin around the clips started to bend. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: bending is not unexpected, judging by the shape they will be hard to pull in, and the can is just thin aluminium.. maybe put a second scrwdriver behind the first and lever off the second one.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue (Halo canister, held to the ceiling with 4 clips). Each of the 4 clips had a round hole. I inserted a Philips head screw driver in one and applied enough pressure to pull it away from the canister case (pulling it towards the center of the canister). This loosened the pressure on the clip and it came off enough to pull it off by hand. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Ravi. Truly appreciate your comment and pointer. Unfortunately, I don't see any place to insert a screwdriver. There was a slight lip where I put a flathead screwdriver but couldn't make the clip budge by even a mm.

Answer (score 1):

New idea: I looked at various photos of the fixture. From the inside you can see the 4 spring clips. You need to lever under each clip at the end farthest away from the bezel. Use a tack puller or other bent tool like a cotter pin remover. To get the distance you might use a bar or fat screwdriver under your lever tool. The spring clip is designed to lock-snap into its final position to press against the top of the ceiling board. Looks like my suggestion is spreading even before I finish typing it.

Comment: Thanks @John-Canon. I tried fighting quite a bit and turn the fixture but no luck. Will try again later after having some spinach :-)